# Array - RESTFUL

Tags: rest, web-services

Is there a way for me to send an array in Restful Web Services?

I am currently using : **@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)**

When I tried to use below code, I always get Null Pointer Exception for the methodClass value.

```
public int adaptiveAuth( @FormDataParam("uuid") String uuID, 
        @FormDataParam("browserinfo") String browserInfo, 
        @FormDataParam("ipint") long ipInt, 
        @FormDataParam("lat") double latiTude, 
        @FormDataParam("longitude") double longiTude, 
        @FormDataParam("sessionid") String sessionID, 
        @FormDataParam("spid") String spID, 
        @FormDataParam("tr") int tR, 
        @FormDataParam("jsnum") int jsNum, 
        @FormDataParam("fingerprint") String fingerPrint ,
         @FormDataParam("methodset") MethodClass[][] methodSet) throws SQLException{
```

Is there any other way for me to send/receive MethodClass[][] in Restful Web Service?

Sample data for MedthodClass[1][1]

Thank you.

Comment: What does the data looks like (for the `MethodClass[][]`)? Is it JSON? Can you post (edit your question by clicking the "edit" link under the tags) an example of this data?

Comment: already edit the question

Comment: @PaulSamsotha you can refer to this post : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663127/http-status-415-unsupported-media-type

Comment: That does show what the actual data is that you are trying to convert to the MethodClass[][].

Comment: @PaulSamsotha

the program will send authStatus and methodStatus in array type [1],[1]

sample data :

 <a:methodSet>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <auap:array>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:methodName>1</xsd:methodName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:methodStatus>1</xsd:methodStatus>
            </a:array>
         </auap:methodSet>

Comment: I don't know. I don't work much with XML.